# Select all child checkbox using parent id - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click `parent 1 check all`button all the child should be slected based on parent id. I have more number of parent each parent have individual id's. How can I do it. I tried some codes its not working. anyone help me on this. Thank you.

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1"> Parent 1 check all
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_3">
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2"> Parent 2 check all <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_3">
</div>
```

Comment: You should include your JS, so we can see what you have tried

Answer (score 7):

As you have wrapped all your inputs in a div, you can use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```js
// I gave the parent a checkall class just for demo cos not sure what your initial selector is:
$('.checkall').on('change', function() {
   $(this).nextAll('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1" class="checkall"> Parent 1 check all
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the solution

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_1"> Parent 1 check all</input>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_1_1">Child 1</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_1_2">Child 1</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_1_3">Child 1</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_1_4">Child 1</input></li>                    
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_2">  Parent 2 check all </input>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_2_1">Child 2</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_2_2">Child 2</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_2_3">Child 2</input></li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="choice_5621_2_4">Child 2</input></li>                    
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="choice_5621_1"]').bind('click', function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', ($(this).is(':checked')));
    });
    $('input[name="choice_5621_2"]').bind('click', function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]', $(this).parent('li')).attr('checked', ($(this).is(':checked')));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess You need to use [the attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$('div[id^="choice_5621_2_"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `siblings` selector of jQuery and select all checkboxes which are at same level.

```js
$('.checkall').on('click', function() {
   $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

//Also making sure if any of the level2 checkbox is unchecked, then uncheck the main checkbox too.

$('.level2').on('click', function() {
   $(this).siblings('.checkall').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1" class="checkall"> Parent 1 check all
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_1" class="level2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_2" class="level2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_3" class="level2">
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2" class="checkall"> Parent 2 check all 
<br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_1" class="level2"><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_2" class="level2"><br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_3" class="level2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the `.closest()` method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The `.parents()` and `.closest()` methods are similar in that they both traverse up the DOM tree

```js
$("#choice_5621_2 , #choice_5621_1").on("click",function(){
  $(this).closest("div" ).find("input[type='checkbox']").not($(this)).prop("checked",$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1"> Parent 1 check all
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_3">
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2"> Parent 2 check all <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox"  id="choice_5621_2_3">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parent").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1" class="parent"> Parent 1 check all
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_1_3">
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2" class="parent"> Parent 2 check all <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_1"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_2"> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="choice_5621_2_3">
</div>
```

But perhaps you should toggle them.

**edit** toggle, like in Pete's answer! and use the nextall instead of parent like I did.

Comment: This allows checked but won't uncheck.

Comment: Where was that requirement listed?

Comment: IMO, it's common sense that if you want to tick all boxes based on the parent, the reverse would also be expected. Afterall - That's how checkboxes work.